# Computing for the closed form of a recurrence relation: Fractions

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

With the given: `T(1) = 1`

How would you compute for the closed form of `T(n) = T(n/4) + 1`?

The way I would answer this is:

```
T(n) = T(n/4) + 1
T(n) = T(n/8) + 1 + 1
T(n) = T(n/16) + 1 + 1 + 1
```

and so on. Is this the correct way of tackling with this equation? Am I missing some important key steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have T(n)=T(n/4)+1

Now find T(n/4) which is T(n/4)=T(n/(4^2))+1 
Therefore the 2nd term would be T(n)=T(n/(4^2))+2 
Similarly kth term would be T(n)=T(n/(4^k))+k 
Now put n=4^k in RHS of above equation, hence we get T(n)=T(1)+k 
=> T(n)=1+k 
but n = 4^k 
 
=> k = log n where base of log is 4. 
hence T(n)= (1+log n ); where base of log is 4.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it is easier to start the other way around: from `T(1)` upwards. We have:

```
T(1) = 1
T(4) = T(4/4) + 1 = T(1) + 1 = 2
T(16) = T(16/4) + 1 = T(4) + 1 = 3
T(64) = T(64/4) + 1 = T(16) + 1 = 4
...
=> T(4^k) = k + 1
```

Can you figure out what the answer is for arguments that aren't powers of `4`? The division is integer division I assume.